# Cmake add_custom_command misunderstanding

Tags: shell, makefile, cmake

I'm learning CMake and struggling with learning the: `add_custom_command` function. 
I'm sorry if this is a basic question but the online documentation didn't help me much.

For this snippet:

```
add_executable (creator creator.cpp)
get_target_property (creator EXE_LOC LOCATION) # get creator.cpp location

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ./created.cpp  # creates 'created.cpp' at the specified path
    DEPENDS creator       # specifies files on which the command depends
    COMMAND ${EXE_LOC}    # executes this command 
    ARGS ./created.cpp
)

add_executable(FOO ./created.c)
```

I can intuitively realise what's going on there, however, I do not understand why each instruction from the body of `add_custom_command` is needed. Here is how I understand it (please correct me where I'm wrong):

- Executable creator is created in the current working dir using creator.cpp
- `EXE_LOC` variable is used to store the path of the created executable
- `add_custom_command`:

  - `OUTPUT` specifies that a `created.cpp` file will be created in the current
    working directory.
  - `DEPENDS`: specifies that this newly created .cpp file depends on the 
    previously created executable. But why do we need to specify this? Is it
    mandatory to do so and if not what happens if I don't specify this
  - `COMMAND: ${EXE_LOC}`: This I don't understand. I assume when the script
    reaches this point some sort of command will be executed. But what exactly is going to get executed here? `./creator` maybe? The documentation specifies that:

    > If COMMAND specifies an executable target (created by ADD_EXECUTABLE) it will automatically be replaced by the location of the executable created at build time.

But I don't really understand this.

- `ARGS`: I don't understand what this is supposed to do and why do we need it. 
   It really confuses me that we pass the newly created file as an argument to a command whose purpose is to create that particular file.
  Please clear this for me if possible.

Thank you for reading my long post.

Answer (score 0):

It is convinient to think about *COMMAND* option as a **command line**:

First, you need to type the path to the program to be executed. In given case it is a path to `creator` executable. Then, you type arguments for given command. In given case, the only argument is a path to the `created.cpp` file. This is what will be executed:

```
<path-to-creator-executable> <path-to-cpp-file>
```

---

Option

```
DEPENDS creator
```

in given case is perfectly described in CMake documentation for [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html):

> If `DEPENDS` specifies any target (created by the `add_custom_target()`, `add_executable()`, or `add_library()` command) a target-level dependency is created to make sure the target is built before any target using this custom command. Additionally, if the target is an executable or library a file-level dependency is created to cause the custom command to re-run whenever the target is recompiled.

In short, this means that before `creator` executable will be run as specified in the *COMMAND* option, the executable will be created and updated if needed.